# $1+X+⋯+X^{p−1}$ is not a product of two non-constant polynomials with nonnegative coefficients, where $p$ is prime.

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime number. How can we show that the polynomial $1+X+⋯+X^{p−1}$ cannot be written in the form $P\times Q$, where $P,Q\in \mathbb R[X]$ are non-constant polynomials with **non-negative** coefficients?

I know that this polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[X]$. If $p$ is not a prime number, then this polynomial can be written in that form. Suppose $p=mn$. Then $1+X+...+X^{p−1}$ $=(1+X+⋯+X^{m-1})$ $(1+X^m+X^{2m}+⋯+X^{(n-1)m}).$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Factoring $1+x+\dots +x^n$ into a product of polynomials with positive coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206805/factoring-1x-dots-xn-into-a-product-of-polynomials-with-positive-coefficie)

Comment: Try to use MathJax not only for the polynomial.

Comment: @OdantArnast I edited your post and replaced "*positive*" with "*non-negative*". Common terminology is to call $\gt 0$ positive vs. $\ge 0$ non-negative. I also removed my dupe vote because this changes the question, though I'll leave the comment since the other post may still be relevant.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @dxiv  I am stupid, the link does answer the question  with equality $(x^p+\cdots +1)(x^q+\cdots+1)=x^n+\cdots +x+1$

Comment: @OdantArnast ? Do you mean that link answers this question of yours directly? I cannot see it yet.

Comment: @OdantArnast But you have not established (yet) that the two factors must be of that form.

Comment: @dxiv  You are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Towards a contradiction, suppose $$1+x\cdots+x^{p−1}=P(x)\times Q(x)$$ where $P(x)=
a_0 + a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots + a_{r-1}x^{r-1} +x^r$, $\ Q(x)=b_0 + b_1x+\cdots + x^s$, $r,s\ge 1$ are integers and $a_0,a_1,\cdots, a_{r-1}, b_0,b_1,\cdots, b_{s-1}$ are real nonnegative numbers.

Thanks to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4583122/580448), we know that each $a_i$ and each $b_j$ is either $0$ or $1$ and that $ a_0=b_0=1$.

Let $x=1$, we get $$p=P(1)\times Q(1).$$

$P(1)=1+\cdots+1$ is an integer $>1$. So is $Q(1)$. Hence, $p$ is not a prime number. That is a contradiction. Our proof is complete.

Comment: Thank you. I believe that we don't need each $a_i$ and each $b_i$ to be either 0 or 1, but only that they are integers.

Comment: Well said.  On the other hand, the easiest way to prove that each of them is an integer might be proving each of them is either $0$ or $1$.